# ffmpeg: Concatenating webm files - output file shows first video only

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm

I have 6 webm files (video/audio) which I captured through WebRTC (web browser getUserMedia API). Individually they all play fine. They're all 15 seconds in length and 2MB in size each.

When I concatenate them with ffmpeg using concat demuxer ([documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)), the resulting output file is 12MB (wchich I expect), but when I play it , it only plays the first video and then it stops after 15 seconds. Tried playing it with Google Chrome as well as VLC.

This is the ffmpeg command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output3.webm
```

And here is mylist.txt:

```
file 'tmpD08D.webm'
file 'tmpD08E.webm'
file 'tmpD08F.webm'
file 'tmpD090.webm'
file 'tmpD091.webm'
file 'tmpD0A1.webm'
```

Here is the ffmpeg output:

```
c:\Temp\files>ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output4.webm
ffmpeg version N-72383-g7206b94 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenc
ore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --ena
ble-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable
-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enabl
e-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable
-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --e
nable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 26.100 / 54. 26.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 33.101 / 56. 33.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, concat, from 'mylist.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fps, 30 tbr,
1k tbn, 1k tbc
[webm @ 00000000003a5fe0] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but con
tainer format requires global headers
[webm @ 00000000003a5fe0] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but con
tainer format requires global headers
Output #0, webm, to 'output4.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.33.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 30 fps,
 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[concat @ 0000000000361e20] DTS 0 < 14911 out of order
[webm @ 00000000003a5fe0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 149
11, current: 0; changing to 14911. This may result in incorrect timestamps in th
e output file.
[webm @ 00000000003a5fe0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 149
11, current: 48; changing to 14911. This may result in incorrect timestamps in t
he output file.
[webm @ 00000000003a5fe0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 148
69, current: 59; changing to 14869. This may result in incorrect timestamps in t
he output file.
```

Note that I see a lot of "Non-monotonous DTS in output stream " errors in the ffmpeg output.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Stream order and properties should be same for all videos.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using mkvmerge which was able to merge the files without a problem.

```
mkvmerge.exe -w -o file1.webm + file2.webm + file3.webm
```

If your files have different audio/video track order, you can use the --append-to option to append different track numbers, as in:

```
mkvmerge.exe -w -o file1.webm + file2.webm + file3.webm --append-to 2:1:1:0,2:0:1:1
```

Format for appending tracks:

```
FILE2ID:VIDEOTRACKID:FILE1ID:VIDEOTRACKID,FILE2ID:AUDIOTRACKID:FILE1ID:AUDIOTRACKID
```

Comment: hi, i met the same problem and use ffmpeg still with 'mkv' container, and it did work out for me.